# express.handlebars not routing properly

Tags: node.js, express-handlebars

I am attempting to access the home route using the express.handlebars method

via https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars

I'm using VSC instead of Atom. Mind overload.

[Here's my explorer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqlQL.png)

my index.js file

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
    const path =require('path');

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home');
    });
```

terminal error

Failed to lookup view "home" in views directory "C:\Users\saved\desktop\stock\views"

When I hover over the home.handlebars file the path within my explorer is true
"C:\Users\saved\desktop\stock\views\home.handlebars"

If I can see it's true when I hover, why is this error occurring?
What am I not seeing?

I've been searching this for almost two days. This exercise was supposed to be my stress reliever. lol

Comment: I think the issue may be that your views folder is inside your public folder? You may want to try moving it up to the main level.

Comment: DANIEL! I wish I could hug you! Thank you. The one thing I had not thought of I didn't do. Smh. I should have disclosed this my first real time using VSC. Atom is so much easier but I needed a challenge.

P.S. have a great weekend and be safe!

Comment: Added this an an answer, if you'd kindly accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make this an official "Answer"... You need to put your "views" folder at the root, not inside `public` :)